# Invalid umlaute character on the post

Tags: blog, language

In our SP2010 environment, have created a blog site and added the category "Schröter". When I try to open the posts under the category "Schröter", it displays properly however the title of category consists of umlaute character(on the posts webpart). Even we have installed German language pack but still the issue persist.

Is it a known issue?